# Reaching outer space using earth's air pressure, then rockets

Tags: rocket-science, space

Please correct me in my methodology if I am wrong, I am only in Physics I right now...

This question has been daunting me for some time, but wouldn't it be a *whole* lot more efficient to send cargo into outer space taking off as an airplane (using thrust form air pressure, i.e. airplanes), and once we reach the upper atmosphere where a jet engines efficiency is gone, we use rockets to propel us wherever we need to go. This would save a-lot of fuel, even though gravity is still pretty strong there, and save a-lot of pollution. What are our potential limits to this theory?

Comment: This is probably too broad of a question to answer in this format. But, check out what are called [Single-stage-to-orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-stage-to-orbit) vehicles, particularly the air-breathing and hybrid types. If you dig into those, you may find specific questions that are answerable here if they are about physics. If it is about engineering, you can check out [Engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) and if it's about space travel, you can check out [Space.SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: In the mean time, welcome to Physics.SE! Check out the [Tour page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/Tour) to get an idea of how our community works.

Comment: Of course, there's also [SpaceShipOne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceShipOne) and it's carrier craft [White Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaled_Composites_White_Knight).

Comment: I recommend that this question not be migrated to space.SE because it would be closed as a duplicate of one of the existing questions on [ssto](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssto). One of those questions asks [Has humanity launched a SSTO … ever?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12552/has-humanity-launched-a-ssto-ever) A comment on the question by SF. notes that *By the way, the lack of SSTO is not because "we can't do it", but because it would be impractical - significantly higher cost for tiny payload.*